# Tiny WCF query times out for one SL client but not another

Tags: wcf, silverlight, timeout

I have a WCF service which my SL app speaks to. I have an older version of the app and a newer version - I've deployed the new version onto the live server and it won't work (just sits there and eventually throws a timeout error)

I've put the original app back in place and put the new app along side it. I've run both and one works, the other doesn't. The debugger for the new app shows that the app is making a call to a few very simple web methods that query the backend DB and return a set of lookup values (in fact I've skipped over all but one of the calls out of curiosity and a single call that returns 3 rows from the DB still times out). I've queried the DB myself and the other app is also querying the same tables so I don't think the problem lies there as I get an immediate response. I've got no idea where to look now...

The strange thing is: occasionally the callback fires and I get a response, but most of the time it times out. This still takes a while though (10-15 seconds)

I've no idea why this has started happening, or why there is a difference between the two applications - both apps are using the same service references and the same app config settings. One works, one doesn't...

I'm starting to pull hair out!

Anyone had a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what it was in the end but it may have been something to do with calling the WCF service in App_Startup (or it might have just been going nuts for a day)

I ended up moving the code out of App_Startup and onto a new 'loading' UC

When the app starts up it uses the loading UC as the RootVisual. This loads the data by calling the WCF service and in the meanwhile displays a holding page.

Once the data is loaded the UC hides the loading screen and adds the main window to it's children collection which gets everything going

I think this is better for the user too as it gives them some feedback that the app has loaded and is busy, rather than just a white screen for a couple of seconds. It also shows them that something is happening in the case that the service is down etc and it doesn't immediately respond

Now I am no longer pulling my own hair out!